# Why isn't RegularExpressionValidator matching my regular expression?

Tags: regex, webforms

I'm having a problem trying to validate a `asp:TextBox` control using a `asp:RegularExpressionValidator`. I've simplified the regular expression that I am using and have isolated that the `RegularExpressionValidator` fails on this part of it: `(?=(.*[A-Z]){2})`, and I don't know why.

This part of the regular expression requires that the input contain a least two upper-case letters. I have tested the expression with the 'Regex' class using LINQPad:

`Regex.Match("THis", "(?=(.*[A-Z]){2})").Dump();`

And also with two online regex testers, and it works with them all.

According the Remarks section in the [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.regularexpressionvalidator%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), the `RegularExpressionValidator` class uses JScript regular-expression syntax on the client. I couldn't find any reference to JScript regular-expression syntax so I assumed that they meant JavaScript, and tested the regular expression against JavaScript using this [Online regex tester](https://regex101.com/#javascript), which shows it works with JavaScript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The whole point is that `RegularExpressionAttribute` requires a full string match. It is not documented, but the [C# source code](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations/DataAnnotations/RegularExpressionAttribute.cs,48) is quite eloquent:

```
override bool IsValid(object value) {
    this.SetupRegex();

    // Convert the value to a string
    string stringValue = Convert.ToString(value, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);

    // Automatically pass if value is null or empty. RequiredAttribute should be used to assert a value is not empty.
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(stringValue)) {
        return true;
    }

    Match m = this.Regex.Match(stringValue);

    // We are looking for an exact match, not just a search hit. This matches what
    // the RegularExpressionValidator control does
    return (m.Success && m.Index == 0 && m.Length == stringValue.Length);
}
```

See **// We are looking for an exact match, not just a search hit. This matches what the `RegularExpressionValidator` control does**.

So, you must add a *consuming* `.*` part of the pattern to the regex, since your `(?=(.*[A-Z]){2})` only matches *partially*, it matches an empty space at the start of the string if there are 2 uppercase ASCII letters in the string, and the `m.Length == stringValue.Length` condition is not met.

**Actually, it can be written better as**

```
^(?:[^A-Z]*[A-Z]){2}.*$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zJ3dB6/1) (it seems the `^` (start of string) and `$` (end of string) anchors are redundant inside your code, the pattern is anchored inside the code).

**Details**:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:[^A-Z]*[A-Z]){2}` - 2 sequences of:

  - `[^A-Z]*` - zero or more characters other than ASCII uppercase letters
  - `[A-Z]` - an uppercase ASCII letter
- `.*` - any zero or more characters other than a newline
- `$` - end of string

Comment: Thank you for your answer Wiktor. I've avoided re-writing as ^(?:[^A-Z]*[A-Z]){2}.*$ as I need to add additional parts to the expression to implement some other rules, such as "must contain at least two lower-case letters", which requires the use of a positive look ahead; using a non-capturing group doesn't facilitate this.

Comment: Sure, lookaheads are easier solution then. Just the full string must match the pattern. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

For this to work with the `RegularExpressionValidator` I needed to add an `.*` to the end of the expression:

```
(?=(.*[A-Z]){2,}).*
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/lhUuDEJGQ7FQfnPa)

---

### Update

[Wiktor's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38667867/909882) explains why adding the `.*` works. Viktor stated that the pattern can be better written as `^(?:[^A-Z]*[A-Z]){2}.*$`, but I haven't followed this as I need to add additional parts to the expression to implement some other rules, such as "*must contain at least two lower-case letters*", which requires the use of a positive look ahead; using a non-capturing group doesn't facilitate this.

Comment: *using a non-capturing group doesn't facilitate this* but the [principle of contrast](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-style.html#contrast) ensures *efficiency* of your lookaheads. A regex for at least 2 letters and at least 2 digits can be written as [`^(?=(.*\d){2})(?=(.*[a-zA-Z]){2}).*$`](https://regex101.com/r/YKFRbT/1) and [`^(?=(\D*\d){2})(?=([^a-zA-Z]*[a-zA-Z]){2}).*$`](https://regex101.com/r/YKFRbT/2) and the difference is tangible (44 vs. 23 steps).